# Check/uncheck all feature not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried to set up a function that can select/unselect all the checkboxes in a view. But it doesn't seem to work at all. Is there something I am missing out?

I based my implementation on the following: http://jsfiddle.net/deeptechtons/TKVH6/.

**detail.html**

```
<li class="item item-checkbox">
    All Services<br>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" ng-model="selectedAll">
    </label>
</li>               
<li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat="e in inventory">
    {{ e.title }}<br>
    <span class="grey-text">&pound;{{ e.price | number: 2 }}</span>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">
    </label>
</li>
```

**controller.js**

```
  $scope.checkAll = function () {
    if ($scope.selectedAll) {
      $scope.selectedAll = true;
    } else {
      $scope.selectedAll = false;
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.inventory, function (item) {
      item.selected = $scope.selectedAll;
    });
  };
```

Comment: Create a plunker demo that replicates problem. Without more scope context your issue is hard for us to troubleshoot. Note that there should *always always always* be a dot in `ng-model` and also you have duplicate attribute on the main checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your code makes no sense. If the value is `true` you set it to `true`, same with `false`, just remove it.

```
if ($scope.selectedAll) {
  $scope.selectedAll = true;
} else {
  $scope.selectedAll = false;
}
```

Also, you would be better off using `ng-change` instead of `ng-click`.

Couple other things: you have added `ng-model` twice to your first input element.

And the main problem is: you're referencing each item in your `ng-repeat` with `e` and within the loop you use `item.selected`. You should be using `e.selected` or change your `ng-repeat` definition:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="e.selected">
```

**OR**

```
<li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat="item in inventory">
```

*In case you go with the latter* you have to change `e.price` and `e.title` to `item.price` and `item.title`.

Comment: I don't understand the "main problem". Why would a local variable need the same name as the scope variable in the child scope?

Comment: Okay, now you edited your question I understand what you mean, but still. He's setting the `selected` property on every single item, so using a local variable there would be just *unused* by the the `checkAll` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you stare really hard at the statement:

```
if ($scope.selectedAll) {
  $scope.selectedAll = true;
} else {
  $scope.selectedAll = false;
}
```

you might notice that the assignments are redundant: you are setting it to `true` if is is already `true`, and to `false` if it is already `false`.

In general, when angular does not do what you expect, debugging your code by setting a break point in the relevant scope method is pretty easy, and will help identify the cause of bugs such as this one.

Answer (score -1):

I would rather not put a function into an input element. What you can do is do a ng-model on the selectAll checkbox and take in an boolean and use that boolean with an ng-if to  check uncheck the other fields. Am I clear?

Comment: *"Am I clear"* ... no , not at all. Provide code to support whatever you are trying to say.